# Convert seconds to minutes:seconds

Tags: r, lubridate

I have the following dataframe

```
case_nr    duration_in_seconds
1.         12.3
2.         6.7
3.         140.5
```

I'd like the following output

```
case_nr    duration_in_minutes_seconds
1.         00:12
2.         00:07
3.         02:20
```

How to achieve in R using packages:

```
library(dplyr)
library(lubridate)
library(stringr)
```

Many thanks

Comment: Is is a `string` column ?

Comment: The comma `,` in your column is confusing.  Is it a dot i.e. `12.3` seconds

Comment: @akrun nope, it's a point actually. changed it in the question.
I don't think it is a string; I'm very new to R and would not know how to recognize

Comment: Are those expected output correct especially the second one

Comment: your third output is wrong: 140.5 seconds - 2 min is 20.5 seconds left, so you cannot have 34 seconds like in your `02:34`

Comment: @akrun I don't mind round-off being not too accurate, 6.7 seconds may be 00:06 or 00:07. Thank you for pointing out; should be 00:07, if rounded correctly.

Comment: @denis I think the OP meant `df1$duration_in_minutes_seconds/60` for the third case.  I was thinking that it is wrong

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Another option is `as_hms`

```
library(hms)
as_hms(df1$duration_in_seconds)
```

---

Or with `as.ITime`

```
library(data.table)
as.ITime(df1$duration_in_seconds)
#[1] "00:00:12" "00:00:06" "00:02:20"
```

#### data

```
df1 <- structure(list(case_nr = c(1, 2, 3), duration_in_seconds = c(12.3, 
6.7, 140.5)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -3L))
```

Comment: I don't think I get it... A real novice here. I've made the following chunk:

Comment: I don't think I get it... A real novice here. I've used as_hms, like you suggested..I've made the following chunk:
```
df1 %>%
    as_hms(duration_in_seconds)
```
and it gives back:

```
Error in as_hms(., duration_in_seconds) : unused argument (duration_in_seconds)
```

Comment: @Quirine_1987 you need `df1 %>% mutate(duration_in_seconds = as_hms(duration_in_seconds))`

Comment: @Quirine_1987 the issue is that you are applying outside `mutate`,, there is no object named `duration_in_seconds` in the global env.  It is in the env of the 'df1' object.  You may either extract the column as `df1 %>% pull(duration_in_seconds) %>% as_hms` or use `mutate`

Comment: Awesome! That worked.. thank you so much. I guess this is real basics here.. but thank you!

Answer (score 3):

base R:

```
paste0(df$duration_in_seconds %/% 60,":",floor(df$duration_in_seconds %% 60))
"0:12" "0:6"  "2:20"
```

data:

```
df <- read.table(text = "case_nr    duration_in_seconds
1.         12.3
2.         6.7
3.         140.5",header = T)
```